# Uninstalling rails from command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to uninstall rails from my computer.Whenever I run the command  gem uninstall rails ,it gives me the following error

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    cannot uninstall, check gem list -d rails`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this cover your question?
[Uninstall Rails completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164697/uninstall-rails-completely)

Comment: Yes it does.Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you have multiple versions of `Rails` installed in your system. Thus, that command might have failed by not deciding which Rails version you intended to remove.

Check your Rails versions by running `gem list -d rails` or `gem list | grep rails` and note the versions (Example, I have 3.2.8, 3.2.5, 4.0.0).

To uninstall any version use:

```
gem uninstall rails -v 3.2.8
```