# Remove Rails from OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Actually the problem is that i want to remove rails from Os x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Rails completely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164697/uninstall-rails-completely)

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you install Rails with

```
gem install rails
```

To uninstall a Rails (or any other gem) use:

```
gem uninstall rails
```

To uninstall all gems at once using:

```
gem uninstall -aIx
```

Comment: Alis-MacBook-Pro:~ aliahmad$ gem uninstall rails -v 4.2.5
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
Alis-MacBook-Pro:~ aliahmad$

Comment: When you used `sudo` to install Rails then you will need `sudo` to remove it.

Comment: sir i have successfully removed rails -v 4.2.5 but when i type Rails -v it still appearing Rails 4.2.5 what to do?

Comment: Since you want to remove all gems anyway you might want to use the command from my updated answer.

Comment: sir i have successfully removed all rails configuration from my max OSX using sudo

Answer (score 1):

To completely uninstall rails use,

```
sudo gem uninstall rails
sudo gem uninstall railties
```

You can also specify version of rails using,

```
sudo gem uninstall rails -v 4.0.0
sudo gem uninstall railties -v 4.0.0
```